# CakePHP create URL from request params

Tags: cakephp

Is there a function to generate the corresponding URL given the request object?

For example, if the request params values are:

```
params => array(
        'plugin' => 'plugin',
        'controller' => 'foo',
        'action' => 'bar',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array()
    )
    data => array()
    query => array(
                'key' => 'val'
        )
)
```

Then, generate the URL:

http://domain.com/plugin/foo/bar?key=val

Comment: You forgot the CakePHP version again. Also it's always helpful to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, that way it's easier to figure a proper solution. That being said: [`Router::reverse($cakeRequestObject, true)`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Router.html#method-Routerreverse).

Comment: CakePHP version 2.3.4

Comment: The Router::reverse worked. If you could post an answer so I could mark it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether this fits your needs depends of course, but generally [`Router::reverse()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Router.html#method-Routerreverse) is able to build a URL from a request object:

```php
Router::reverse($cakeRequestObject, true)
```

It's much like [`Router::url()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router%3a%3aurl), but it will do all the dirty work for you like including the query values and removing unnecessary parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use Router::reverse() like that way :

```
$url = Router::reverse($this->params);
echo $url;
```